# Determine if $S$ a vector space when it is a subset of $C([-1,1])$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $C([-1,1]$ be the set of continuous functions on the interval $[-1,1]$, and let $S$ be the subset of $C([-1,1])$ consisting of $f$ such that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for any $x$ in $[-1,1]$. Is $S$ a vector space?

So this is one of the questions from my textbook and from the answers in the textbook, I know that $S$ is a vector space. I am having trouble with determining of how $S$ is a vector space when it involves intervals.

I know the axioms for determining whether something is a vector space but how would I apply them with the intervals?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You con show that, if $f$ and $g$ are in $S$ and $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ then $f+\lambda g\in S$, i.e $(f+\lambda g)(-x)=-(f+\lambda g)(x)$ $\forall x\in [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

it suffices to prove that $S$  is a vectorial subspace of $\mathcal C([-1,1])$.

For this you can remark that  that $0 \in S$  and show that  if  $f,g \in S$  and $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, then $f + \lambda g \in S$

Answer (score 0):

You can also show that, for any $x\in [-1,1]$, the map $h_x:x\mapsto f(-x)+f(x)$ is linear and it's Kernel is a vector subspace, and remark that $S=\bigcap_{x\in [-1,1]}\ker h_x$ which is a vector subspace.